# How to generate MD5 hash of UDID in iPhone

Tags: xcode, md5

I have tried a lot but not able to figure out that how to generate a `MD5 hash` of `UDID` code of iPhone device.

Reason: I have to use that hash as a background password to login the website.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Can try below code for converting UDID string into MD5.

```
 #import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
NSString *hashStr = [self converIntoMD5:udid];



- (NSString *)convertIntoMD5:(NSString *) string{
    const char *cStr = [string UTF8String];
    unsigned char digest[16];

    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call

    NSMutableString *resultString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [resultString appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    return  resultString;
}
```

Comment: to fix the warning modify this line
CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest );
to this one:
CC_MD5( cStr, (unsigned int)strlen(cStr), digest);

Answer (score 1):

`uniqueIdentifier` iOS (2.0 and later) Deprecated: Use the identifierForVendor property of this class or the `advertisingIdentifier` property of the `ASIdentifierManager` class instead, as appropriate, or use the `UUID` method of the `NSUUID` class to create a `UUID` and write it to the user defaults database.